# Integral solutions of polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

The equation 
$$
a_n x^n+\dots+a_0=1, \qquad a_n\neq 0, \qquad a_i\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
has $\geq 4$ distinct integral solutions. How can I prove that 
$$
a_n x^n+\dots+a_0=-1
$$
has no integral solution?

Comment: It does have an integral solution.  Take x = 0 and a_0 = -1.

Comment: @D.B. but since $a_i$ are integral, you can not satisfy the first condition with $a_0=-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$. Suppose $p,q,r,s$ are four distinct integers such that $$f(p)=f(q)=f(r)=f(s)=1.$$
Then,
$$f(x)=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s) \,\,g(x)+1, \quad \text{where } g(x) \text{ is some polynomial in } \Bbb{Z}[x].$$
If $t \in \Bbb{Z}$ is such that $f(t)=-1$. Then,
$$f(t)=-1=(t-p)(t-q)(t-r)(t-s) \,\,g(t)+1.$$
This is same as saying
$$(t-p)(t-q)(t-r)(t-s) \,\,g(t)=-2$$
Observe that $t \not\in\{p,q,r,s\}$ and the left side is a product of integers. Can you now arrive at a contradiction?